# Windows 8 Application Javascript and SQlite (Database is locked)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, windows-runtime

I write some simple app for windows 8 Metro UI with javascript. Because natural method from microsoft to use Sqlite with Javascript in Metro UI. I use 'doo' wrapper: 
[dooWrapper SQLite (github)](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT)

I create a method :

```
function addSomething(name) {
    var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\a_db.sqlite';
    SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath).then(function (db) {
        return db.runAsync("INSERT INTO STH (nazwa) VALUES (:name)", { name: name }).
        done(function () {
            console.log('Add sth : ' + name);
            db.close();
        }, function (error) {
            if (db) {
                db.close();
            }
            console.log('ERROR Adding sth' + error.message);

        })
    });
}
```

I get error 'database is locked' I read about this error in documentation. But I have one question is other solution to add more rows without create 'insert' function  with collections argument something like that : insert (array) ? I just want to use that function n-times without this error. That's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,it possible...i also got this error before....For that you just need to establish the database connection once...i have used this in my app and its working fine.
If there is no need of closing your db then then open database once like..

Add this code to default.js file

```
var myDatabase; //Global Variable
var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\db.sqlite';


//Create Table
          SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath).then(function(db) {
        myDatabase=db;
                return db.runAsync('CREATE TABLE Item (name TEXT, price REAL, id INT PRIMARY KEY)');

                });
```

Then you just need to use below code

```
// For Insert
        return myDatabase.runAsync('INSERT INTO Item (name, price, id) VALUES ("'+ array[i].name+'", "48484", 1);
```

For array

```
    var dbPromises = [];


    var testArray = [];
    //only for test purpose
    //You can pass your array here directly
    for (var a = 0; a < 300; a++) {


            var obj = {
                name: "Mango"+a,
                price: 100+a,
                id: a
            };

            testArray.push(obj);

    } 

    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {

        var query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Item (name, price, id) VALUES ("' + testArray[i].name + '",' + testArray[i].price + ',' + testArray[i].id + ')';

        dbPromises.push(globalDatabase.allAsync(query));
    }


WinJS.Promise.join(dbPromises).then(function () {

    debugger;
}, function(err) {

    debugger;
});
```

Above code is used only for less array size...bcz its taking too much time for insertion...
For fasst execution you should replace just below code

```
 for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {


        var val = '("' + testArray[i].name + '",' + testArray[i].price + ',' + testArray[i].id + '),';
        query = query + val;

        if ((i + 1) % 300 == 0 || (i + 1) == testArray.length) {

            query = query.replace(/,$/, "");
            dbPromises.push(globalDatabase.allAsync(query));
            query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Item (name, price, id) VALUES ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes,this is a perfect solution. Evan this apply in my app also.